# How would I put 2 elements into a single row in an array?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have some code that searches email titles and looks for certain keywords.  For a certain group of these emails, there will always be two results.  What I would like to do is add both these results to a single row of an array.  Currently I have:

```
ArrayList<String> Dlist = new ArrayList<String>();

if (subject.length() >=14 && subject.matches(leavingto))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < clients.length; i++){
        if (subject.contains(clients[i].getAbbr()))
            Dlist.add(clients[i].getAbbr());
    }
}
```

This adds the matches to an array (Dlist) but each match is a separate entry.

Comment: Are you using a two dimensional array? What do you mean by row in an array?

Comment: Sorry I am currently actually using an array list.    ArrayList<String> Dlist = new ArrayList<String>();

Comment: There is no concept of rows in ArrayList as I am aware of. ArrayList uses a single dimensional array to store objects.

Comment: Have you tried putting a class object inside of your `ArrayList` where you enumerate the cases? Or maybe another list (ie., a list of lists)?

Comment: Can you include your declaration of Dlist?

Comment: Edited to add declaration.  I realize it is not an array but an arraylist.  Sorry about that.  Do I need to use an array instead?

Comment: @ Myles Baker - I tried briefly to do a separate arraylist and then make an array of those lists but either I was getting the syntax wrong or that is not what it was designed to do.   This is my first java project and I am learning as I go so I might be misunderstanding arraylists compared to arrays.

Comment: @ThomasBartley Thanks for the context. I suggest you delete this question and ask about how to approach the problem rather than posting code. For example, if you explain what you're trying to accomplish the community will help you structure your code and think about the problem. This is also a much more effective way to learn long-term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine those two as a String array. Then add the String array to the ArrayList.

```
ArrayList<String[]> Dlist = new ArrayList<String[]>();

...

String[] s = new String[2];
s[0]="firstvalue";
s[1]="secondvalue";
Dlist.add(s);
```

Comment: This ended up working for me.  Not sure if its the most efficient way to do it, but ended up using .split and searching each part of the string.